# Returning to login page after registration is done

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How do you return to a previous page after it has been left. For example my app opens to the loggin screen, you can login or register when you register it takes you through a multipage and multi view controller process. When the registration finishes I want them to be taken back to the starting loggin page.

Can anyone help me on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, which you would use for example if the View Controller was presented modally. You might also want to try `popViewControllerAnimated` if you are using Navigation Controller.

I'd recommend reading the [UIViewController Class Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) or the [UINavigation Controller Class Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a navigation controller (which would be highly recommended in a multi-VC process) the best solution would be using Unwind Segues.

You can see [Apple's Documentation on using them](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html), but to briefly explain the process:

1. Create a method on your login page with the signature `@IBAction unwindToLogin(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)`
2. Create a segue in the View Controller you want to go back to the login screen from that leads to the view controller's exit icon. The exit icon is shown below

[image: Exit Icon]

3. When creating the segue, select the `unwindToLogin` function and give it an identifier if you are planning to call it programmatically.
4. Treat it how you would any other segue, and it should work!

Comment: What going inside the method? or is it just @IBAction unwindToLogin(segue: UIStoryboardSegue); Also how do you create a segue?

Comment: @JoeKuzera The method doesn't need anything going on inside unless you want it to; it just needs to exist. The method is how Swift knows which view controller you want to unwind to. I strongly recommend you follow the link in the question: [Apple Unwind Segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html). It detailedly explains the process. But, put briefly, control drag from the yellow icon in the picture above to the exit icon, and create an "unwind" segue with the name of the method you created, give it an identifier, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier()`